# Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc,

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.3500.o,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. No crystal reports installed.Pls. contact administrator.

Answer (score 0):

1.On your solution, right-click on **References**, then click on **Manage NuGet Packages**
2. Choose the **Browse** tab.
3. In the search box type *CrystalReports*
4. Install the Package

Comment: I installed crystal packages, but the error still occurs.